# How do I expand the background image to fill the entire page?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm creating an animation of the fixed-place button at the top left that creates a background that spreads across the page when clicked.So I wrote a CSS like this:It only expands to the parent element, but how do I make it an animation that stretches to the entire page?

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at center, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-size: 10% 10%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div:hover {
    background-size: 200% 200%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the height and width to [`100vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units) and [`100vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units) respectively

I've also added  CSS to the `body`, to stop the scrollbars appearing when the element is full-sized

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 10% 10%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all .5s;
}

div:hover {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  background-size: 200% 200%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but appears to move to the right as the circle expands. Can I keep this circle fixed while expanding?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that's just a consequence of expanding the width / height - I tried `position: absolute` and `position: sticky` along with setting `top` and `left`, but wasn't having much luck - Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a pseudo element like below:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -100vh;
  bottom: -100vh;
  left: -100vw;
  right: -100vw;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, blue 50%, transparent 50%) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  transition: all .5s;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.box:hover::before {
  background-size: 200% 200%;
}

html {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: When I tried the answer code, there was a difference between the set transition time and the time until the screen was filled with the background image. Do you have a way to match these two durations exactly?

Comment: @stefano it's difficult to match them exactly because the trick rely on having a big element that overflow the screen to make sur to cover the screen. Unless the box is alwys having a fixed width/height and always at the same position

Answer (score 0):

Change the `height` and `width` properties to `100vh` and `100vw` respectively.

- `vh` - viewport height
- `vw` - viewport width

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at center, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
    background-size: 10% 10%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div:hover {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-size: 200% 200%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```